# How to set scroll bar scale view position of chart to recently added value using c#

Tags: c#

> In my Application i'm using chart control and updating real time values continuously every one seconds.I enabled scroll bar for the chart and the scroll bar is working fine.But i want to set the scroll bar position to the recently added value(right side) always. Pls guide me,

```
 Chart chart = new Chart();
 Series series1 = new Series("testing");
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.AutoScroll = true;

 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 15;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.All;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;

 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;                
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(2, 5);
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Jacobr365: I searched in google. But there is no solution for this.

Comment: You could try to trigger the ScrollBar.Scroll event and tell it where to put the bar too.

Comment: Simply set the Maximum (and Minimum) to the values you want! (Assuming you have proper, numeric x-values) or set `AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(firstDataPoint, lastDataPointInView);`

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found solution to keep the scroll bar position to the recently added value.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
```

> AxisX.Maximum is the recently added value to the chart.